# Algorithm to work out top ten most viewed

Tags: php, algorithm, formula

Ok so I have a database table that contains a list of famous people and for each person there is a field called Views to count how many times that particular person has been viewed. I was wondering if anyone knows of a simple formula/algorithm that would take all the people in the table and work out the top ten viewed obviously in descending order.

I would need to put this into PHP code I'm guessing using a combination of IF statements.

Any help on this would be great!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are happy to help you correct problems with your existing code, but we will not, in most cases, write that code for you. For better results, please show what you have tried and explain how that attempt does not meet your requirements.

Comment: Have a look at the `ORDER BY` SQL command ...

Comment: Obviously? Letterman does it in ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM PEOPLE 
ORDER BY VIEWS DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I'd normally write some explanation with code though this is so trivial (it's almost plain English), let me know if anythins is unclear to you ;)

Comment: Oh of course! It was staring me right in the face, it can be done in the SQL statement itself. Thank you for pointing this out to me!

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new, if you feel this answer is the right answer accept it by clicking the mark on the left. This notifies future visitors of this page of the correct answer.